# keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\Administrator\.keystore

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

First i executed this command:
`keytool -genkey -alias vendavodev1 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -storetype jks -keystore vendavo.keystore`

After that when i execute this command:
`keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias vendavodev1 -file certreq.txt`

I get the following error:
`keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\Administrator\.keystore`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first command you define the keystore name with `-keystore vendavo.keystore`

You also need to pass this argument to second command, otherwise the default keytore is used.
`keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias vendavodev1 -file certreq.txt -keystore vendavo.keystore`